# Laravel Valet logs

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, fpm, laravel-valet

I'm using laravel valet to serve sites in my local dev env, which is great. However, there's only one file in the expected location of `~/.valet/Log`:

```
➜ ls ~/.valet/Log 
nginx-error.log
```

I've tinkered with php-fpm log settings and the nginx log settings, but I'm not sure that I'm even using the right config files, since I suspect that valet installs its own version of PHP and nginx.

Can any one tell me where the php / nginx config files for valet would be found, and what specific settings to change to drop the PHP error / log files where they're supposed to be written?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Hopefully this helps with your question about the nginx config files. You can find the nginx configuration for your sites by running `cd ~/.config/valet/Nginx` in your terminal. To get to the base nginx config for valet use `cd /usr/local/etc/nginx/valet`. You should then see `valet.conf`, inside you can update the following lines to put the log files where you want them.

```
access_log "/Users/[user_id]/.config/valet/Log/access.log";
error_log "/Users/[user_id]/.config/valet/Log/nginx-error.log";
```

Make sure to run `valet restart` after you make changes to the valet.conf file.

Comment: Ok, what about the PHP error logs?

Answer (score -6):

The NGINX configuration file should be available at /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf